# How to move the product navigation arrows in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

[The arrows of product navigation are marked in the link. Pls have alook at it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0S4m.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using CSS, you can move little bit right most of the page. to avoid merge with title.